# how to wget https on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, wget, ash

I am wanting to try [installing a hosted reddit](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/reddit-install-script-for-Ubuntu): 
I just installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 on VirtualBox.
Then i tried to run: 
`$ wget https://raw.github.com/reddit/reddit/master/install-reddit.sh`
 from the built in shell (ash) that begins lines with (initramfs)
But it tells me `"not an http or ftp url"`
In the installation process i also installed postgresql db..
i also tried on http, but it tells me `"bad address raw.github.com"`
What did i do wrong? Or how do i properly wget this script?

Comment: How is the network configured in the VirtualBox VM? Can you ping 8.8.8.8 (the google DNS)? How is you resolver configured?

Comment: oh ok, it appears i havent configured networking yet. sorry, i am new to Ubuntu/linux. this is probably why its not working then. thanks

Comment: now im lost.
following this [configure networking tutorial](http://windy.me.uk/howto-2/run-ubuntu-12-10-server-in-virtualbox/)
it tells me to edit a copy of etc/network/interfaces but there is no such file on my install, nor do i have access to sudo, su, ping commands. Also, i chose not to do updates in the install process.

Comment: i reinstalled. i didnt install dns first time it seems.

Comment: i can now ping google and download the script from github. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't installed DNS. Silly mistake.

> During the Server Edition installation you have the option of installing additional packages from the CD. The packages are grouped by the type of service they provide.
>
>
> 1. DNS server: Selects the BIND DNS server and its documentation.